# How to switch out AndroidX Architecture Component task executor for Espresso tests

Tags: android, androidx, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

We've run into problems with a flakey Espresso tests and are pretty certain the cause is a `LiveData#postValue` call. It seems Espresso will sometimes make assertions before all tasks have been executed on the `ArchTaskExecutor` instance.

It seemed to me that this problem should be solveable with use of `IdlingResource`: we could swap out the `ArchTaskExecutor` for one we integrate with `CountingIdlingResource` to make sure Espresso is aware of tasks being executed. It seems however that it isn't possible to set the executor being used as `ArchTaskExecutor#setDelegate` is only available within the arch library itself. We could of course stop using `postValue` and use a Handler (with the main looper) integrated with `CountingIdlingResource`. So we don't have to do that is there any other way of switching out or integrating with the `ArchTaskExecutor` to have Espresso be aware of when and when not it's idle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some digging I found that [`CountingTaskExecutorRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/arch/core/executor/testing/CountingTaskExecutorRule) is available in the [AndroidX Arch package](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/arch). This can be used to build out an idling resource like so:

```java
public class CountingTaskExecutorIdlingResource extends CountingTaskExecutorRule implements IdlingResource {

    private IdlingResource.ResourceCallback resourceCallback;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return CountingTaskExecutorIdlingResource.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        return isIdle();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(IdlingResource.ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIdle() {
        resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is slightly wrong, `onTransitionToIdle` is meant to be called asynchronously the moment your resource becomes idle, so in this case you want to subclass CountingTaskExecutorRule and override its `onIdle` method to call `onTransitionToIdle()`.

See their example code for it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/0905d0e307ef457a4c37511a542edfe3bdb4d2a3/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/util/TaskExecutorWithIdlingResourceRule.kt#L61-L66)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I used the linked example and the (now very much improved) [Idling Resource docs](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource) to put together an updated answer.